# How to specify which columns can be returned from linq to sql query

Tags: sql, linq, explicit, construction

I'm trying to only return a few columns from a linq to sql query but if I do, it throws the exception:

**Explicit construction of entity type 'InVision.Data.Employee' in query is not allowed**

Here's the code:

```
return db.Employees.Select(e => new Employee()
       { EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID, FirstName = e.FirstName,
         LastName = e.LastName }).ToList();
```

If I return everything then it will throw exceptions about circular references because it needs to be serialized to be used in javascript, so I really need to limit the columns... Thanks for any tips you can give me to solve this.

Comment: I don't think there are any strong arguments for not returning the entire Employee object. Performance is certainly not one. Linq will take care of not returning any associations unless they are accessed.

Comment: @cdonner I suppose it would be appropriate to return all columns when the following four conditions are true: A) You have SSD drives for your SQL instances, and B) Have 10GBps connections to SQL SAN units, and C) Have twice the memory on all your SQL servers and application servers, and D) Have more SQL core licenses than you know what to do with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, if you just want the columns, select those.  If you want the employee entity, select it.  There's not much of a middle ground here.  I recommend against creating a new class just for this.  Yuck!

Do this:

```
return db.Employees
   .Select(e => new { e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName, e.LastName })
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but the function returns List<Employee>, and if you just do new without specifying Employee then it won't compile because the query will return List<AnonymousType#1>. I ended up finding the solution:

var query = from e in db.Employees 
                      select new { e.EmployeeID, e.LoginName, e.FirstName, e.LastName }; 
            var typedQuery = from e in query.AsEnumerable() 
                           select new Employee { EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID, LoginName = e.LoginName, FirstName = e.FirstName, LastName = e.LastName };
            return typedQuery.ToList();

Comment: That sort of works.  But I still don't like it because the caller of your function most likely expects the full Employee object, and you're not giving it to him.  Instead of doing all of this, I suggest returning IQueryable<Employee> and returning the whole Employee object.  Because you're returning IQueryable and not a list, execution will be deferred to your caller, who can select what they want in their method...

Comment: Can this be specified dynamically, such as with a comma separated string?

Answer (score 3):

Because I've had to fight with Linq2Sql and Serialization before I'd recommend using a View object to handle this scenario rather than a Linq2Sql Entity.  Its a much easier solution:

```
return db.Employees
        .Select( e => new EmployeeView() 
        { 
            EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID, 
            FirstName = e.FirstName, 
            LastName = e.LastName 
         }).ToList();
```

The other alternative is to drag a new copy of your Employee table into the DBML designer, name it something different like SimpleEmployee, delete all the relationships and remove all the columns you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Justin,

Explanation of that error here:
http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/04/25/linq2sql-explicit-construction-of-entity-exception.aspx

One thing you can do is create a class that derrives off of Employee.

```
public class EmployeeProxy : Employee
{
}
```

then you can do your query:

```
return db.Employees.Select(e => new EmployeeProxy { EmployeeID=e.EmployeeID, FirstName=e.FirstName, LastName=e.LastName }).ToList();
```

On the other hand, if you only need to serialize the result set to javascript, then you can also just use anonymous classes.  This works as well:

```
return db.Employees.Select(e => new { EmployeeID=e.EmployeeID, FirstName=e.FirstName, LastName=e.LastName }).ToList();
```

Hope this helps.